# How to reset inbuilt HTML input validity

Tags: javascript, html

In Firefox, at least, native HTML5 input element validity, e.g. a `required` text field, shows up as a red border, but *only after interaction*.

e.g. in the example below, I initially see two input boxes. If I type something in one of them, delete it and press Tab, the first one now glows red to show me it's invalid (because it's required).

**Using Javascript, how can I reset the form to the pristine initial state, where the red border is not showing?**

```html
<form action='#'>
  <div>
    <input required name="a" type="text"   />
    <input required name="b" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way I've found is to reset the form, either via a `<button type="reset">` or through [`form.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset).

Note, however, that this will wipe the values of any and all fields in the form, so if you need these to remain you'll need to repopulate their values after the reset is done.

Setting `<form novalidate>` will work, however subsequently removing the `novalidate` attribute will make the field(s) show errors again.

Comment: Excellent, `form.reset()` - but also `formElement.reset()` - is what I needed. Many thanks